# HTML/CSS Align objects in center with float

Tags: html, css, web, alignment

so I got this issue, I want to align objects in center but those objects have float: left;

This is what it looks like on 100%
[image]

This is what it looks like 150%
[image]

Code:

```
.holder {
text-align: center;
display: table;
margin: auto;
}

.box {
width: 360px;
height: 130px;
border-radius: 2px;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="holder">
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `display:inline-block;`?

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: @alirezasafian i added HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `float:left` it will ignore the property `text-align:center` so you can use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` it will work perfect.

Try once!